# Не собирается библиотека на boost::python в c++

Tags: c++, python, boost

Visual Studio.
В настройках example добавил в каталоги библиотек `vc++` `python/include`, `python/lib`s, корень `boost_{version}`, `boost/stage/lib`, где скомпилированные `boost_ dll`-ки, при этом не компилится код из `wrap.cpp`:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include "some.h"

using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
    class_<Some>("Some")
        .def(init<int, string>(args("some_id", "name")))
        .def("ID", &Some::ID)
        .def("Name", &Some::Name, return_value_policy<copy_const_reference>())
        .def("ResetID", static_cast< void (Some::*)() >(&Some::ResetID))
        .def("ResetID", static_cast< void (Some::*)(int) >(&Some::ResetID), args("some_id"))
        .def("ChangeName", &Some::ChangeName, args("name"))
        .def("SomeChanges", &Some::SomeChanges, args("some_id", "name"))
        .add_static_property("NOT_AN_IDENTIFIER", make_getter(&Some::NOT_AN_IDENTIFIER))
        ;
}
```

Не хочет использовать пространство имён `boost python`, не включается заголовочный питон, не определены идентификаторы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yXw8rgUw1y8

Также нужно добавить Python/include во включаемые и Python/libs в библиотеки, иначе будет "ошибка: не удалось найти pyconfig.h"